# Apache Airflow unable to establish connect to remote host via FTP/SFTP

Tags: ssh, ftp, sftp, airflow

I am new to Apache Airflow and so far, I have been able to work my way through problems I have encountered.

I have hit a wall now.  I need to transfer files to a remote server via sftp.  I have not had any luck doing this.  So far, I have gotten S3 and Postgres/Redshift connections via their respective hooks to work in various DAGs.  I have been able to use the FTPHook with success testing on my local FTP server, but have not been able to figure out how to use SFTP to connect to a remote host.

I am able to connect to the remote host via SFTP with FileZilla, so I know my credentials are correct.

Through Google searching I have found the [SFTPOperator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/sftp_operator.py), but am not able to figure out how to use it.  I have also found [FTPSHook](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/_modules/ftp_hook.html), but still I have not been able to get it to work.

I keep getting the error `nodename nor servname provided, or not known` or a general `Operation timed out` in my Airflow logs.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Should I be using the FTPSHook with SSH or FTP Airflow Conn Type?  Or do I need to utilize the SFTPOperator?  I am also confused as to how I am supposed to setup the credentials in my Airflow connections.  Do I use the SSH profile or FTP?

If I can provide any more additional info that may help, please let me know.

Cheers!

Comment: SFTP and FTP are two completely different protocols. You cannot connect with FTP (or FTPS) to SFTP server.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I appreciate it.  I know they are two different protocols.  I should have worded my question a bit better as to not give the impression that I am confusing the two.  I think s7anley's answer below is what I was looking for.  Cheers!

Comment: It's still not late to edit your question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SFTPOperator` is using `ssh_hook` underhood to open sftp transport channel that serves as a basis for file transfer. You can either configure `ssh_hook` by yourself or provide connection id via `ssh_conn_id`.

```
op = SFTPOperator(
    task_id="test_sftp",
    ssh_conn_id="my_ssh_connection",
    local_filepath="",
    remote_filepath="",
    operation=SFTPOperation.PUT,
    dag=dag
)
```

Comment: I ended up using the pysftp library within a custom operator, but this looks like it's exactly what I need to keep with the consistency of the code base.  Thank you!!!!