# Apache Airflow Unable to fetch file over SFTP

Tags: sftp, airflow

I'm using the sftp_operator from Airflow v1.9rc5. I'm trying to fetch two files over SFTP but I'm getting:

ERROR - Failed connecting to host: 192.168.56.101, error: No authentication methods available

I have the connection ID set up for this remote host. I've also verified the connections from BASH using the SFTP command.

FTP fetch task:

```
sftp = SFTPOperator(
        task_id='fetch_data',
        ssh_conn_id='sftpid2',
        local_filepath='/Users',
        remote_filepath='/',
        operation=SFTPOperation.GET,
        dag=dag
        )
```

Comment: This might help: [Apache Airflow unable to establish connect to remote host via FTP/SFTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46307762/3776858)

Comment: Thank you, I saw that and followed the example, but I still can't figure out why I'm getting this error.

Comment: I was able to get SFTP to work by using SSH key instead of UID and PW. To use the SSH key with the connection ID, you will need to set the path to your key in the extras field of your connection definition. 

{"key_file": "/PATH TO YOUR KEY/.ssh/KEYNAME_rsa"}
The key cannot be password protected. 

Also with Airflow v1.9rc5 I was having issues updating the extras field. I was getting the error message of "invalid padding" when trying to add the key path. I had to revert back to v1.8, update then run v1.9 again. 

I'm not sure if SSH Key is currently the only supported method.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the UI was not updating the password field in the database for that connection ID. so when you tried to SFTP using user ID and PW, it would fail. If you updated the password field in that record, everything works as expected. So SFTP works with either SSH Key or UID and PW.

Comment: how do you update the password field in the database? Also what connector type did you configure in airflow (FTP or SSH)? I only have UID & PW authentication for an SFTP server I am trying to download files from the server using airflow but cannot authenticate.

Comment: You can use SQLite3 commands to query the DB, but you shouldn't need to other than needing to verify the records. The connection type in airflow should be SSH for SFTP.  When we updated the version of Airflow to v1.9 a few things were fixed. IIRC there was a issue with the UI saving the credentials into the DB. But since v1.9 that's been resolved. So.... you should not need to manually update the record with the PW.